# how to remove fixed position from menu hamburger icon

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the fixed position from the hamburger icon so that I can position it relative to its parent div? Ive added this to a header in elementor but I cannot adjust the position by adding padding/margins etc to the header as it is fixed. I need to be able to add padding in the header using vw units so that the hamburger icon moves when the browser is resized. Ive tried changing some of the "position:fixed" css in here but not had any succcess achieving what I need yet.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+Mono+One|Roboto+Mono:400,700&display=swap');
:root {
  --color-primary: #18181A;
  --color-secondary: #75757C;
  --color-dark: #364C62;
  --color-light: #F5F5F5;
  --font-family-primary: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  --font-family-secondary: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
  --td: 150ms;
  --te: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: var(--color-dark);
  font-family: var(--font-family-primary);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem + 4vmin);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
a {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.page-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 45rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.page-container > * + * {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
.nav-main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  transition: left 0s calc(var(--td) * 2), transform 0s calc(var(--td) * 2);
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-main::before, .nav-main::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--td) var(--te);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
.nav-main::before {
  top: 0;
}
.nav-main::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.nav-main .menu__item {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-1rem);
  transition: opacity var(--td) var(--te), transform var(--td) var(--te);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  z-index: 100;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span {
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  width: 2rem;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  background-color: var(--color-dark);
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before {
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(-100%);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(100%);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span {
  transform: rotate(1turn);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main {
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0s;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::after {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) / 2);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--te), transform calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--te);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (1 * 0.25));
  z-index: -1;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (2 * 0.25));
  z-index: -2;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (3 * 0.25));
  z-index: -3;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (4 * 0.25));
  z-index: -4;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (5 * 0.25));
  z-index: -5;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > .menu__item {
  font-family: var(--font-family-secondary);
  font-size: 10vmin;
}
.submenu {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
.submenu .menu__item {
  font-family: var(--font-family-primary);
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
}
.submenu .menu__link {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 var(--color-primary), 2px 2px 0 var(--color-primary);
}
.submenu .menu__link::before, .submenu .menu__link::after {
  display: none;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__link::before, .menu__item:hover .menu__link::after {
  animation: blink 1s var(--td) steps(1, end) forwards infinite;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 0.5rem));
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__link::after {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) / 2);
}
.menu__item:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 2) calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te), opacity calc(var(--td) * 2) calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te), visibility 0s calc(var(--td) * 3);
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu__link {
  color: var(--color-dark);
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.125rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color var(--td) var(--te), opacity var(--td) var(--te), transform var(--td) var(--te);
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu__link::before, .menu__link::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--color-light);
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform 0s var(--te);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu__link::before {
  top: 0;
}
.menu__link::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu:not(:focus-within):not(:hover) .menu__item .menu__link {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.menu__item {
  --pull: 30%;
}
.menu__item .menu__link {
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
  transform: translate(0, calc(var(--pull) * -1));
}
.menu__item .submenu .menu__link {
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu__item:hover > .menu__link {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.menu__item:hover > .menu__link:hover {
  color: var(--color-light);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu__item:hover ~ .menu__item > .menu__link {
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
  transform: translate(0, var(--pull));
}
@keyframes blink {
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="main-navigation-toggle" class="btn btn--close" title="Toggle main navigation" />
<label for="main-navigation-toggle">
  <span></span>
</label>

<nav id="main-navigation" class="nav-main">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Clients</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Burger King</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Southwest Airlines</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Levi Strauss</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Services</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Print Design</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Web Design</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Mobile App Development</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main class="page-container">
  <h1>Fork This Nav Challenge</h1>
  <p>Click the toggle to open the menu and see the magic.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? I added a wrapper around both the menu and the menu toggle (which allows you to maintain your relative CSS selectors to show/hide the navigation). The container is `position:relative` and I added a right margin to demonstrate your scenario above. I also changed the toggle label to `position:absolute` so it would follow the container.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+Mono+One|Roboto+Mono:400,700&display=swap');
:root {
  --color-primary: #18181A;
  --color-secondary: #75757C;
  --color-dark: #364C62;
  --color-light: #F5F5F5;
  --font-family-primary: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  --font-family-secondary: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
  --td: 150ms;
  --te: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: var(--color-dark);
  font-family: var(--font-family-primary);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem + 4vmin);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
a {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.page-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 45rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.page-container > * + * {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
.navigation-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}
.nav-main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  transition: left 0s calc(var(--td) * 2), transform 0s calc(var(--td) * 2);
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-main::before, .nav-main::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--td) var(--te);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
.nav-main::before {
  top: 0;
}
.nav-main::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.nav-main .menu__item {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-1rem);
  transition: opacity var(--td) var(--te), transform var(--td) var(--te);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  z-index: 100;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span {
  display: block;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  width: 2rem;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  background-color: var(--color-dark);
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te);
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 1rem);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::before {
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(-100%);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"] ~ label span::after {
  transform: rotate(0) translateY(100%);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span {
  transform: rotate(1turn);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ label span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main {
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0s;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::before, [id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main::after {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) / 2);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--te), transform calc(var(--td) * 2) var(--te);
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (1 * 0.25));
  z-index: -1;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (2 * 0.25));
  z-index: -2;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (3 * 0.25));
  z-index: -3;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (4 * 0.25));
  z-index: -4;
}
[id="main-navigation-toggle"]:checked ~ .nav-main .menu__item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) * 2 * (5 * 0.25));
  z-index: -5;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu > .menu__item {
  font-family: var(--font-family-secondary);
  font-size: 10vmin;
}
.submenu {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
.submenu .menu__item {
  font-family: var(--font-family-primary);
  font-size: 3.5vmin;
  width: 100%;
}
.submenu .menu__link {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 var(--color-primary), 2px 2px 0 var(--color-primary);
}
.submenu .menu__link::before, .submenu .menu__link::after {
  display: none;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__link::before, .menu__item:hover .menu__link::after {
  animation: blink 1s var(--td) steps(1, end) forwards infinite;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 0.5rem));
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
}
.menu__item:hover .menu__link::after {
  transition-delay: calc(var(--td) / 2);
}
.menu__item:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform calc(var(--td) * 2) calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te), opacity calc(var(--td) * 2) calc(var(--td) * 3) var(--te), visibility 0s calc(var(--td) * 3);
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu__link {
  color: var(--color-dark);
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.125rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color var(--td) var(--te), opacity var(--td) var(--te), transform var(--td) var(--te);
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu__link::before, .menu__link::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--color-light);
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-110%);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform 0s var(--te);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu__link::before {
  top: 0;
}
.menu__link::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu:not(:focus-within):not(:hover) .menu__item .menu__link {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.menu__item {
  --pull: 30%;
}
.menu__item .menu__link {
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
  transform: translate(0, calc(var(--pull) * -1));
}
.menu__item .submenu .menu__link {
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu__item:hover > .menu__link {
  color: var(--color-secondary);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.menu__item:hover > .menu__link:hover {
  color: var(--color-light);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.menu__item:hover ~ .menu__item > .menu__link {
  transition-duration: calc(var(--td) * 3);
  transform: translate(0, var(--pull));
}
@keyframes blink {
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="main-navigation-toggle" class="btn btn--close" title="Toggle main navigation" />
  <label for="main-navigation-toggle">
    <span></span>
  </label>

  <nav id="main-navigation" class="nav-main">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#0">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Clients</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="menu__item">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Burger King</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Southwest Airlines</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Levi Strauss</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Services</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="menu__item">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Print Design</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Web Design</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Mobile App Development</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#0">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<main class="page-container">
  <h1>Fork This Nav Challenge</h1>
  <p>Click the toggle to open the menu and see the magic.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: problem is i just tried to put the hamburger menu inside a div with relative/absolute, and the actual on click doesnt work anymore. If you are able to edit my code above that would be awesome as im at bit of a loss with it

Comment: amazing thanks, almost there now. i cant seem to figure out the positioning on it now, ive removed all margins/padding etc that i can see but the hamburger icon is sitting in the top center of the div, i need it on the right. have a look at it on mobile on the [page](https://daisy.garywestjr.com/dj-snake) im working on and you will see what i mean. any ideas?

Comment: Did you get it? I'm seeing it on the top right in Edge/Chrome.

Comment: if you look on mobile (or drag browser to smallest width) youll see it isnt in line with the image below. I have 7% padding around the header and i need the menu to sit against the right edge which would line it up with the right edge of the hero image. As far as i can see in the code ive removed all padding/margins but theres clearly something pushin it to the left and up.

Comment: if you go on dev tools and highlight the header you will see how its out of position

Comment: All I'm seeing is that it's pushed 43 pixels in because of `right: 43px` on the label span.

Comment: ahh ok removed that, its still pushed slightly to the left and up though?

Comment: The `<span>` needs a height at smaller screen widths. It looks like you're only setting a height (125px) for larger screens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216808/discussion-between-gjjr-and-brandon-gano).